# Separate Applications on IIS for Angular client and .Net Core WEB API

Tags: angular, iis, deployment, asp.net-core-webapi

Which is the best practice while deploying angular 2+ applications with .net core web Api's in IIS

1. Deploying both the Angular Client and the .Net Core Web Api as a single application or
2. Creating two different applications one for Angular Client and another application for .Net core Web Api application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create two different applications as it gives you the flexibility

- Two develop features on each of those, deploy the applciation quickly
- If you need you can deploy the Angular Client to static storage
- If you want to change your deployment to other services, you can easily switch it later. For ex containerize api